# Is there a way set a break-point (eg. when named function is called) programatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, breakpoints, developer-tools

I am working on some JavaScript - of course! - and am doing some debugging in Chrome.

Now, I would like to enable a break-point *programatically* when a function (with a given name) is called.

1. It should function like a break-point. The `debugger` keyword always breaks (uhg!) and is an ugly artifact to put in and remove from code.
2. It should not require manual source code navigation / interactivity. Since the source is combined through an automated build process this becomes a time-consuming endeavor.

Ideally it would be as something as simple *and programatically controlled*, eg.

```
Debugger.setBreakpoint({onFunction: "Foo.prototype.bar"})
```

---

Is there a way to set a break-point for when a particular (named) function is called *without* manual navigation of the currently loaded script?

If not as envisioned programatically, is there a way to set a break-point *via* a comment? (Break-point, not `debugger`-break.)

(I am amendable to using similar developer tools in another browser, as long as it runs on Windows - but a Chrome solution, if such exists, is ideal.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Chrome Developer Tool you can use [`debug(function)`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#debugfunction) statement to invoke function and break inside of it.

One more way if you have a exact function reference
`var func = function(){
    if (arguments.callee._debug) {
        debugger;
    }
}`

set `_debug` flag to `true`
`func._debug = true`

then function `func()` will be stopped. It's tricky and this will not work it `strict mode`.

Comment: @user2864740 great. I've just edited comment and added one more way

Comment: The `debug(..)` solution fits the bill perfectly, especially since this only a current debugging artifact! I can't believe I never knew about it before.

Answer (score 3):

How about you write one function in which you can place your breakpoint:

```
function setBreakpoint (fn) {
    return function () {
       debugger;
       fn.apply(this, arguments)
    }
}
```

And in your console you override the function you want to break on:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = setBreakpoint(Foo.prototype.bar);
```